# Text sorting/align/spacing algorithm needed

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

I don't know how to call this, but is there an algorithm for this kind of sort? Going from input to output.

Input:

```
Article evident arrived express highest men
did boy. Mistress sensible entirely am so.
Quick can manor smart money hopes worth too.
Comfort produce husband boy her had hearing.
Law others theirs passed but wishes. You day
real less till dear read. Considered use dispatched
```

Output:

```
Article evident arrived  express  highest  men
did     boy.    Mistress sensible entirely am         so.
Quick   can     manor    smart    money    hopes      worth    too.
Comfort produce husband  boy      her      had        hearing.
Law     others  theirs   passed   but      wishes.    You      day
real    less    till     dear     read.    Considered use      dispatched
```

Here is all I wrote, I think honestly this is the peak of my skill... I would appreciate if someone could maybe link a tutorial that is somewhat related to my problem.

```
int highestnr = 0;
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Text, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] parts = lines[i].Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int k = 0; k < parts.Length; k++)
            {

                if (parts[k].Length > highestnr)
                {
                    highestnr = parts[k].Length;
                }

            }
        } 
        using (var write = File.CreateText(Results))
        {
            foreach(var something in lines)
            {
                string[] parts = something.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                StringBuilder NewLine = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    NewLine.Append(' ', highestnr);
                    NewLine.Append(parts[i]);
                }
                write.WriteLine(NewLine);
            }

        }
```

I know that the  code gives spaces only according to the highest word count instead of seperating by columns, that is out of my scope...

Comment: @Hogan It took me 3 statements, one of which is 3 lines because I put the LINQ method calls on separate lines. Consider the usefulness of two parameter `Select` and `GroupBy`.

Comment: Without using LINQ, my general approach is to `String.Split` your source (`List<string>`) into words (`List<string[]>`) and store in a variable. Then find the max words in a line, and find the max length word for each word position (from `0` to max). Now you just process the words list again, using `PadRight` to reformat each word in each line to the max length you found for that position, and then `String.Join` the words back into sentences.

Comment: @NetMage -- makes sense.  3 lines in linq is a lot, since most things can be done in one line.

Comment: Looking at your sample code, change `highestnr` to be an array on max `parts.Length` (it is would be poor to just pick a number like 1000, but OTOH dynamically growing a `List` is a bit tricky), then index `highestnr` by `k` when finding the max per position. Then index `highestnr` by `i` when outputting, and swap the output of `parts[i]` and the spaces (or use `String.PadRight`).

Comment: Sorry I was trying to figure out what you meant for me to do , but I have no clue. I was trying to parse highestnr as an array , but I can't declare it at as a 0 at that point and then it won't allow me to compare and find the highest number.

Comment: You would need `int[] highestnr = new int[1000];` for example. Since it is a value array, each member would be set to `default(int)` automatically, which is `0`.

Comment: @Hoggan I found it straightforward, but you are right, looking back at a lot of LINQ code, it is only for some pretty difficult things that I use that many lines. Of course, I often use extension methods to generalize and simplify complicated LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

an example of solution: i am using easy code to help to understand

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Text, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
        int maxnbcol = 0;
        List<int> maxlgbycol = new List<int>();
        int[] maxpaddingbycol;
        List<string[]> stfile = new List<string[]>();

        //split each line and put the result in list<string[]>
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var lineplitted = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (lineplitted.Length > maxnbcol) maxnbcol = lineplitted.Length;
            stfile.Add(lineplitted);
        }

        maxpaddingbycol = new int[maxnbcol];

        //calcul the max padding for each column
        for (int numline = 0; numline < stfile.Count; numline++)
        {
            for(int numcol = 0; numcol < stfile[numline].Length; numcol++)
            {
                var lgword = stfile[numline][numcol].Length;
                if (lgword > maxpaddingbycol[numcol])
                    maxpaddingbycol[numcol] = lgword;
            }
        }

        //apply padding and rebuild each line
        for (int numline = 0; numline < stfile.Count; numline++)
        {
            for (int numcol = 0; numcol < stfile[numline].Length; numcol++)
                stfile[numline][numcol] = stfile[numline][numcol].PadRight(maxpaddingbycol[numcol]);

            var newline = String.Join(" ", stfile[numline]);
            Console.WriteLine(newline);// --> you could call your method to write an output file
        }
```